# Parameter 'info' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: node.js

I have this piece of code:

```
const format = winston.format;

    format: format.combine(
                            format.colorize({ level: true, message: false }),
                            format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }),
                            format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
                        )
```

but when I compile the project I got this error:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'info' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

with the solution proposed I got this error:

```
src/common/logging/logging.service.ts:95:43 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

95                         format.printf(info:any => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
```

Comment: what is `format` ? What is format.combine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need a brackets

```
format.printf((info:any) => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Typescript error. It expects you to define a type for the 'info' argument. You can replace `info` with `info:any` for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved as @BerkOzturk suggested by providing :any type.
By default the typescript compiler expects that you will provide type for every variable.

The other solution for this issue is to say compiler to stop doing that by setting noImplicitAny to false in tsconfig.json file.